# Attach webcam to android tablet, is it possible?

Tags: tablet, usb-peripherals, webcam

I have a Logitec C120 webcam (its wire is an USB).

I also have an ASUS transformer infinity (which has an USB port).

Guess what I tried... but the asus does not seem to respond to the webcam in any way.

... can it be made to work?

Comment: You may wish to refer to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35706/connecting-multiple-usb-devices-using-a-usb-hub-that-connect-to-the-usb-port-of