# Connecting multiple USB devices using a USB hub that connect to the USB port of a Android devices

Tags: usb, tablet, usb-peripherals

Is it possible to use and connect a USB Hub on any generic and major Android tablets that only have 1 USB port and connecting multiple USB devices (depending on how many port the USB Hub have) such as the following:

- USB PC keyboard
- USB PC mouse
- USB Camera
- USB Floppy drive
- USB CD/DVD Writer
- USB Fan
- USB Thumbdrive/Flash drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tablets support USB hubs.

[Source](http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/android-tablet-q/31224-using-usb-hub-android-tablet.html)

Answer (score 3):

Typically yes, you can use a USB hub to connect multiple devices without any issues. Whether or not these peripherals perform adequately may depend on the amount of power that they require, but that's common to un-powered USB hubs in any situation.

Google's Android support pages actually mention USB hubs. E.g. [the Nexus S support page on keyboards and other devices](http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2386439) specifically states:

> To connect more than one USB device at a time, use a powered USB hub to reduce the drain on your phone’s battery.